# Select MySQL records based on expiry timestamp and current date time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column named expiry which stores expiry date time in form of Unix timestamp. I want to select the records which are not expired.

```
SELECT * FROM user_subscription WHERE username = ? AND expiry < NOW()
```

For example, if expiry is equal to 1601427661 which is around 30 Sept 2020 6AM then that record should not be selected because it's expired.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_subscription 
WHERE username = ? 
  AND expiry < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

Answer (score -1):

use FROM_UNIXTIME() to convert datetime

```
where username= ? and FROM_UNIXTIME(expiry)>now()
```

Comment: This prevents using an index on `expiry`